# Karate: Form data params not logged in POST requests

Tags: karate

After upgrade from 0.9.6 to 1.0.0 I noticed that the logging of the POST requests seems changed, and the params present as form parameters are not visible in the logs.

Is there a way to activate them again? It is very hard to debug without them.

1.0.0

```
    # 1 > POST https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
    # 1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    # 1 > Content-Length: 9
    # 1 > Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
    # 1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
    # 1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.7)
    # 1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
```

0.9.6

```
    # logging will show something like:
    # 1 > POST https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users
    # 1 > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    # 1 > Content-Length: 9
    # 1 > Host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
    # 1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
    # 1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.7)
    # 1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
    # user=test
```

https://github.com/aleruz/karate-call-single-bug/blob/main/src/test/java/examples/users/create-user-post-form.feature

Reproducible running

`mvn test "-Dkarate.options=--tags @create-user-post"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1525

Anyone is welcome to submit a PR.